# ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Использую в *React* приложении "Таблицы" *`mobx`*. 
Когда нажимаю на кнопку развернуть строки получаю ошибку:

> ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.
> at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89997:58)
> at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:90016:7.

Если удаляю `observer`  с компонента `Cell`, то ошибки нет, но тогда не отслеживается изменение ячеек. 
Так же нет ошибки, когда не вызываю жизненный цикл `getDerivedStateFromProps`, но он тоже важен. 
Решения просматривал предлагаемые, но не увидел подходящего.